# WordPress display parent element as active when current page is the child

Tags: wordpress, menu, element

I use the `wp_nav_menu` function to integrate a custom menu. When I request a parent's child element the parent element also should have the class `current-menu-item`.

For example, I call Gallery » **MyFirstGallery**, the Gallery element should be shown as an active element.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "gallery" li item has classes

```
.current-category-ancestor 
.current-menu-ancestor 
.current-menu-parent 
.current-category-parent
```

Style it like .current-menu-item